# Multithread jdiameter client (load testing plugin)

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, mobicents, diameter-protocol

Good afternoon. 
This program is very important and difficult challenge for my team. 
We need to write the implementation JDiameter client to server load testing (simple implement JMeterPlugin.JavaSampler). Please help advice or reference.

1. Now when I pick up a second connection from the client to the same config, I get an error:

> 2015/09/17 16:14:11 ERROR - ru.at_consulting.autotest.diameterclient_mod.AutotestLogger: AvpHelper: Error during message send --> Unable to find valid connection to peer[192.168.200.120] in realm[vimpelcom.ru] 
>   org.jdiameter.api.RouteException: Unable to find valid connection to peer[192.168.200.120] in realm[vimpelcom.ru] 
>       at org.jdiameter.client.impl.router.RouterImpl.getPeer(RouterImpl.java:431) 
>       at org.jdiameter.client.impl.controller.PeerTableImpl.sendMessage(PeerTableImpl.java:176) 
>       at org.jdiameter.client.impl.StackImpl.sendMessage(StackImpl.java:428) 
>       at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl.genericSend(BaseSessionImpl.java:121) 
>       at org.jdiameter.client.impl.BaseSessionImpl.genericSend(BaseSessionImpl.java:88) 
>       at org.jdiameter.client.impl.SessionImpl.send(SessionImpl.java:60)

2. How can I increase the load:
   to implement a singleton DiameterClient and send a copy of it flows?
   to create multiple connections with different configs customers? 
   Correct configuration of the client?

Comment: Look into this code, it sends more than one request http://jdiameter.googlecode.com/git-history/1.4.0.CR3/examples/charging-server-simulator/src/main/java/org/mobicents/servers/diameter/charging/ChargingServerSimulator.java